Unit Test Flutter: Login API (POST) with email and password as payload
I am writing this Unit Test in Flutter. It's Login API (POST) with email and password as payload. Do i need to pass password and email as hardcoded as arguments in userLoginApi fieild?
group(
    "User Auth - ",
    () {
      group(
        'get Auth function',
        () {
          test(
              'given Login Authentication class when loginApi Func is called'
              ' status code is 200 then a user model or 1 should be returned',
              () async {
            //Arrange
            // Act
            final result = await loginController.userLoginApi(password: '12345',email: 'xyz@gmail.com');
            debugPrint("resulttt $result");
            // Assert
            expect(result, 1);
          });
        },
      );

Do i need to pass password and email as hardcoded as arguments in userLoginApi fieild?

One way is to use environment variables.
Pass from a command-line:
flutter test --dart-define=EMAIL=xyz@gmail.com

Parse in a code:
String email = const String.fromEnvironment("EMAIL")

See Environment declarations for details.
